# SonarQube don't start after adding a new plugin

Tags: sonarqube-4.5, sonarjs

After adding "sonar-javascript-plugin-2.9.jar" in Sonar\sonarqube-4.5.1\extensions\plugins ,I restart SonarQube that don't start .

After searching, I find that it will be forbidden to kill all process (elasticsearch.....) which are activated. and other person suggest to change (#sonar.search.port=9001) to (sonar.search.port=0) in sonar.properties but without result.

Please, can you give me your suggestions ?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube 4.5.1 and SonarJS 2.9 are both old and are not supported anymore. The current ["Long term support" version of SonarQube is 5.6.6](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/).

Moreover, [SonarJS 2.9 requires at least SonarQube 4.5.2](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/commit/ed63e78ca4a43b246350cd8bfff102fe220dbf21).